# Form file field value not posting to $_POST

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I'm doing some tests with forms and ran into a snag, I have a very simple test script that works, but the problem is that my FILE field in the form is not getting submitted to the $_POST array for some reason, if I take out encode="multipart/form-data" it does, otherwise I just get the other fields. Here is the script:

```
<?PHP
print_r($_POST);
echo"<br>";
print_r($_FILES);

$name = $_FILES["img1"]["name"];
$tmp_name = $_FILES["img1"]["tmp_name"];
$uploads_dir = "uploads";
echo "<br>TEMP NAME:</b>";
echo $tmp_name;
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
?>

<html>
<body>
<br><br>
-------------------------
<form name="test" id="test" action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="title" id="title">
<br>
<label>File</label>
<input type="file" name="img1" id="img1" size="40">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

The output is:

```
POST ARRAY: Array ( [title] => some title )
FIELS ARRAY: Array ( [img1] => Array ( [name] => chicken.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpcrBLw9 [error] => 0 [size] => 30940 ) )
TEMP NAME:/tmp/phpcrBLw9
```

As you can see, the POST only has the title, not the file name, I need it to have both for programming reasons, is there a way to do that without having to cheat / have hidden fields or edited values manually?

Comment: `$_FILES["img1"]["name"]` is the filename, `$_POST["title"]` is the title field..

Comment: why do you need the file name in POST? whata do you want to do??

Comment: I'm using it inside Joomla and it has a very weird way of doing things, this means I will need to do things manually, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to see $_FILES inside $_POST. They are different superglobals, if you `vardump($_FILES);` you will see that it stores all the information about the uploaded file, like size, tmp name etc. This is how PHP has been built, and the only thing you can do about it is access the name using

> $_FILES['img1']['name']

Answer (score 1):

You can access the name of the uploaded file here:

```
$_FILES["img1"]["name"]
```